# How to play a video from directory in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to play video from the local directory in Qt QML.

For now I playing video from resource file but my goal is to call the local directory and play one by one all the video inside that directory. Is it possibly do that in Qt QML?

```
Video {
    id: video
    autoPlay: true
    loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
    source: "qrc:/Resources/samplevideo.mp4"
}
```

Comment: replace `qrc:/` with `file:/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get file list of particular folder and iterate over it using [`FolderListModel` QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html):

```
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.12
// ...
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    /// Put here URL of folder with videos
    folder: "file:" + "/home/tro/Videos/"
    /// Put a list of file name filters
    nameFilters: ["*.avi"]
    showDirs: false
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (folderModel.status == FolderListModel.Ready) {
            console.log('Folder Model Loaded')
            console.log("Folder list contains ", folderModel.count, "elements:")
            for (var i = 0; i < folderModel.count; ++i) {
                console.log("\t", i, folderModel.get(i, "fileURL"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, see documentation on [method `get`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#get-method) to understand better what you can get (e.g. here we use only `fileURL`).